# Prove the following refinement of AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

Under what additional condition(s) the following inequality would be holds. In this case, prove your assertion and the inequality.
For $x,y \ge 1$ (with $x \ne y$) we have
    \begin{align}
 \alpha x + \beta y \ge \alpha x + \beta y - {\rm{e}}^{\frac{{2 - \left| {x - y} \right|}}{{\left| {x - y} \right|}}}  \ge \alpha x + \beta y - {\rm{e}}^{\frac{{1 - \beta ^\alpha  \alpha ^\beta  \left| {x - y} \right|}}{{\beta ^\alpha  \alpha ^\beta  \left| {x - y} \right|}}}  \ge x^\alpha  y^\beta   \label{eq2.3}
 \end{align} 
    for all $\alpha,\beta \in [0,1]$ such that $\alpha+\beta=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first inequality is obvious.

The second inequality is equivalent to $$\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}\leq\frac{1}{2},$$ which is true by Jensen and AM-GM:
$$\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\ln\beta+\beta\ln\alpha}\leq e^{\ln(\alpha\beta+\beta\alpha)}\leq e^{\ln2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The last inequality is wrong.

Try $\alpha=\beta=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x-y\rightarrow0.$

Comment: Thank you. my question now is how to fix the last inequality? what you think if we add $|x-y|>0$

Comment: @Mohammad W. Alomari In the general it's an interesting question. For specific $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I can write something, but in the general it's not so easy.